# Java (JSP/Servlet): equivalent of getServletContext() from inside a .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How should I access the ServletContext from a .jsp? For example, how can I call the *getRealPath* method from inside a .jsp.

Here's a Servlet, which works fine:

```
protected void doGet(
            HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType( "text/html; charset=UTF-8" );
        final PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.print( "<html><body>" );
        pw.print( getServletContext().getRealPath( "text/en" ) );
        pw.print( "</body></html>" );
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
```

Now I'm looking for the exact line I'm supposed to insert in the following *.jsp* to do exactly the same thing as the servlet above is doing.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <body>
     ...  // What should I insert here   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964250/jsp-getservletcontext-error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ServletContext` is accessible via the `application` implicit object.

Since each JSP is a servlet, you can also use `getServletContext()`.

But.. avoid having code like that in the JSP. Instead, obtain the value you need in your servlet and set it as a request attribute, simply reading it in the JSP (via JSTL preferably)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
${pageContext.servletContext}
```

Comment: From the question: *"For example, how can I can call the getRealPath() method from inside a .jsp"*?

Comment: @Webinator: that method requires a String parameter so you cannot call it through `${}` notation. There are at least 3 different approaches exist: 1)You can call this method inside a bean (the best for the case IMHO) 2) You can create a custom tag and call it from there 3) You can write a scriplet (`<% //some code here %>`) - the worst IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work fine on a JSP Page:

```
<body>
<%
out.print(getServletContext().getAttribute("attribute"));
%>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `application.getRealPath(" ");`.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking to use the getRealPath() method, you might consider looking into a jstl tag called 'c:url'

```
<c:url value="text/en" />
```