# jsp getServletContext() error

Tags: jsp, servlets, weblogic

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Murach's Java Servlets and JSP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%-- import packages and classes needed by the scripts --%>
    <%@ page import="business.*, data.*" %>

    <%
        //get parameters from the request
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");

        // get the real path for the EmailList.txt file
        ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
        String path = sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");

        // use regular Java objects
        User user = new User(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);
        UserIO.add(user, path);
    %>
    <h1>Thanks for joining our email list</h1>
    <p>Here is the information that you entered: </p>
    <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">First name:</td>
            <td><%= firstName %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Last name:</td>
            <td><%= lastName %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Email Address:</td>
            <td><%= emailAddress %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>To enter another email address, click on the Back <br />
    button in your browser or the Return button shown <br />
    below.</p>

    <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Return" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and it's giving me this error page...

> **Compilation of 'C:\bea\user_projects\domains\mydomain.\myserver.wlnotdelete\extract\myserver_sample01_WebContent\jsp_servlet__display_email_entry.java'
>   
>  failed:**
>   C:\bea\user_projects\domains\mydomain.\myserver.wlnotdelete\extract\myserver_sample01_WebContent\jsp_servlet__display_email_entry.java:140:
>   cannot resolve symbol
>  probably
>   occurred due to an error in
>   /display_email_entry.jsp line 19:
>   ServletContext sc =
>   this.getServletContext();
>
> **Full compiler error(s):** C:\bea\user_projects\domains\mydomain.\myserver.wlnotdelete\extract\myserver_sample01_WebContent\jsp_servlet__display_email_entry.java:140:
>   cannot resolve symbol
>  symbol  : method
>   getServletContext () 
> location: class
>   jsp_servlet.__display_email_entry
>       ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext(); //[
>   /display_email_entry.jsp; Line:19]                                    ^
>                              
> 1 error 
> Thu Jun 03 15:56:09 CST 2010

any hint? I'm really new to JSP, and this is my first learning practice... can't find it by google.com....

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JSPs in Weblogic behaves differently from Tomcat with respect to getServletContext

Replace `ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();`

to `ServletContext sc = getServletConfig().getServletContext();`

Comment: the link in the previous comment is no more available

Comment: wow it worked on weblogic !!! what about websphere application server ? is it the same there also ?