# Java EL to find host and port number in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, port, el, host

I am trying to find a base url (host, port, context) within the jsp page using EL.
I know how to do this on servlet/jsp like this

```
    StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String ctx = request.getContextPath();
    String base = url.substring(0, url.length() - uri.length() + ctx.length()) + "/";
```

I was searching over the web and found this clue on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/2898407/2515808 about expression language.

```
    ${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

Using this I am able to find out the application context path only. Could you please help me find host and port number as well.

Thanks

Comment: Below link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989888/get-request-url-in-jsp-which-is-forwarded-by-servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

Is just calling `getContextPath()` at request object, to access other things you can do:

```
${pageContext.request.requestURI} 
${pageContext.request.requestURL} 
${pageContext.request.serverPort}
```

etc. This way you can call any getter(with no parameters) of request just as you've done in servlet. Also since EL 2.2 you can directly call methods in EL